# NavigationModel with iOS17 Observation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm playing around with new [@Observable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/observation) and kind of stuck around how to make properties bindable if it's inside environment object.

So, in app i've setup navigation programmatically as apple suggests "[Robust Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bringing_robust_navigation_structure_to_your_swiftui_app)"

and NavigationModel is injected as environmentObject and property columnVisibility is a part of same model and passed as a binding property to NavigationSplitview
With new Observation macro, seems like we can pass properties from environment object as binding.

```
final class NavigationModel: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var selectedCategory: Category?
    @Published var recipePath: [Recipe]
    @Published var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility
    }

 NavigationSplitView(
        columnVisibility: $navigationModel.columnVisibility
    )
```

With Observation Macro

```
@Observable
final class NavigationModel {
 var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .automatic 
}
```

When trying to do the same, it fails
[image]

[image]

Is there something i'm missing ?

One solution i can think of is move columnVisibility to some other class and make it Observable using macro or define property in same view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a variable with the `@Bindable` property wrapper in the view's body linked to your model.

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Managing-model-data-in-your-app#Change-model-data-in-a-view):

> You can use the Bindable property wrapper on properties and variables to an Observable object. This includes global variables, properties that exists outside of SwiftUI types, or even local variables. For example, you can create a @Bindable variable within a view’s body

So, your code would look like this:

```
struct HomePageView: View {
    @Environment(NavigationModel.self) var navigationModel

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var navigationModelWithBinding = navigationModel
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $navigationModelWithBinding.columnVisibility)
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the conversion to `@Bindable`:

```
@Bindable var navigationModel = navigationModel
NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $navigationModel.columnVisibility)
```

You wouldn't have needed this if you used an `@State` struct instead of a class.